# Existence and uniqueness of solutions for higher order ODE with complex linear coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a quick theoretical question: For $1 \leq k \leq n$, let $a_k(t) = \alpha_k t +
\beta_k$, where $\alpha_k, \beta_k$ are complex numbers. Does the
$n$-th order differential equation 
$$a_0(t)f(t) + a_1(t)f'(t) + \cdots + a_n(t)f^{(n)}(t)=0$$
together with given (complex) initial values for $f$ and its first $n$
derivatives always have a unique solution? Here $f(t)$ is a complex
valued function in the real variable $t$.

In the literature, I could only find results for real coefficients.
Any reference would be appreciated.

Thank you very much,
Francois

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By writing all the functions in terms of their real and imaginary parts and setting the real and imaginary parts of the whole expression equal to zero separately, you obtain an equivalent linear system for two real-valued functions. This is then susceptible to the usual real techniques (which normally reduce higher-order ODEs to systems of first-orders anyway).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!